# Вывод текста из файла .txt на страницу HTML через ajax через промежуток времени

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Подскажите как реализовать - вывод в html, текст из txt в html средствами ajax ?

Comment: Раз в N-ое время посылаете AJAX запрос, его результат обрабатываете и выводите в нужный вам компонент.

Comment: я понял это - а как это делать ?

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать? и что конкретно у вас не получилось?

Comment: сам запрос не получается - пример бы посмотреть

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp - можете тут посмотреть, либо же в офф документации http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: это не совсем то - я смотрел эти примеры ! надо что бы при нажатии на ctrl+s - html обновлялся автоматом и выводилось то что там написано - Я искал это но примеров нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36961/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-vartlok).

Comment: в Вашем вопросе ничего нет о "ctrl+s". Что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Возможно, live reload?

Comment: ну а как же писать в txt и не нажимать на "сохранить" ?

Comment: наверно live reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён самостоятельно - выход был на  jqueryRefresh